# Unable to connect to paypal sandbox on EC2 linux instance (LAMP)

Tags: php, paypal, amazon-ec2, sandbox

I recently moved my site from godaddy to EC2. Paypal sandbox integration worked properly on godaddy but is not connecting on EC2.

Below are the details from error log - please help fix this.

```
*   Trying 173.0.82.83...
* Connected to api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com (173.0.82.83) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
* skipping SSL peer certificate verification
* ALPN/NPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* SSL connection using TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
* Server certificate:
*       subject: CN=api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com,OU=PayPal Production,O="PayPal, Inc.",L=San Jose,ST=California,C=US
*       start date: Jan 14 00:00:00 2016 GMT
*       expire date: Jan 14 23:59:59 2018 GMT
*       common name: api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com
*       issuer: CN=Symantec Class 3 Secure Server CA - G4,OU=Symantec Trust Network,O=Symantec Corporation,C=US
> POST /nvp HTTP/1.1
Host: api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 886
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

* upload completely sent off: 886 out of 886 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Tue, 27 Sep 2016 22:09:13 GMT
< Server: Apache
< X-PAYPAL-OPERATION-NAME: SetExpressCheckout
< X-PAYPAL-API-RC:
< Connection: close
< HTTP_X_PP_AZ_LOCATOR: sandbox.slc
< Paypal-Debug-Id: 862f6baf38447
< Set-Cookie: X-PP-SILOVER=name%3DSANDBOX3.API.1%26silo_version%3D1880%26app%3Dappdispatcher_apit%26TIME%3D166652503%26HTTP_X_PP_AZ_LOCATOR%3Dsandbox.slc; Expires=Tue, 27 Sep 2016 22:39:13$
< Set-Cookie: X-PP-SILOVER=; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT
< Content-Length: 138
< Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
<
* Closing connection 0
[Tue Sep 27 22:16:14.570092 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 18998] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Sep 27 22:16:14.677382 2016] [suexec:notice] [pid 19084] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Tue Sep 27 22:16:14.699763 2016] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 19085] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Tue Sep 27 22:16:14.700363 2016] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 19085] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Tue Sep 27 22:16:14.719996 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 19085] AH00163: Apache/2.4.23 (Amazon) PHP/5.6.25 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Sep 27 22:16:14.720013 2016] [core:notice] [pid 19085] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd'
```